# Wsadmin connect to remote Profile, ADMA0043E exception

Tags: installation, websphere, wsadmin

I am trying to install an application on websphere using wsadmin:

```
AdminApp.install('D:\work\my.ear',['-cluster', 'Vivaldi', '-MapWebModToVH', [['.*', '.*', 'default_host']]])
```

and get en error: `ADMA0043E: /ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv02/config/temp/upload/my5776587604736184411.ear does not exist for installation`

Websphere is running as user1, wsadmin script from user2
it is possible to install the application via wsadmin from another user?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User2 doesn't have write permissions to /ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv02/config/wstemp.

You'll need to allow user2 to write to this directory and subdirectories.

Additionally, the script may fail because user2 doesn't have permissions to the OSGI configuration. If so, you'll need to set a system property for wsadmin:

```
/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv02/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -javaoption "-Dosgi.configuration.area=/home/user2/.eclipse" ...
```

It should be noted that IBM assumes that wsadmin.sh will always be run as the installation user, in this case user1. The official, supported way to do what you want is to install an "adminstrative client" as user2 either on this server on on another server. (and then specify the host and soap port) This will avoid the permissions issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does the AdminApp.install comman work if you run WebSphere and install the app?

Comment: Yes, but only when I started wsamin with the same user as websphere